# ¿Cómo lanzar los mensaje de validación de html a traves de javascript o jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, validación

Estoy haciendo el envió de un formulario a través de la función submit de jquery, el problema es que no toma en cuenta los campos requeridos y hace el submit incluso cuando estan vacios, esto no sucede cuando se tiene un boton tipo submit en el formulario.

El siguiente ejemplo no toma en cuenta el atributo required en el campo nombre:

```js
$("#btn").on('click', function (){
  $("#main").submit();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="main" name="main" method="post" action="">
      <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" required></input>
      <button id="btn" type="button">ok</button>
</form>
```

El siguiente ejemplo con un boton submit lanza los mensajes de validacion:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="main" name="main" method="post" action="">
      <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" required></input>
      <button id="btn" type="submit">ok</button>
</form>
```

**¿Como se pueden activar o lanzar estos mensajes de validacion a traves de jquery o javascript?**

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo por medio del evento click del boton, comprobar validación, y sí es así realizar tu función.

```js
$("#btn").on('click', function (){
  //verificar que tu formulario esté correcto
  let bandera = $("#nombre") != "";
  //preguntar por tu validación
  if(bandera)
    $("#main").submit();
  else
    alert("No cumple los requisitos");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="nombre" type="text"></input>
<button id="btn" type="button">ok</button>
```